# cannot connect to X server error showed up in GCP

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, google-cloud-platform, xserver

I create a python GUI by PyQt4, and now I'm trying to save this program into Google Cloud Platform(Compute engine) so that I can remotely execute it. But after I execute my python program, there's a problem showed up, the console showed the message :"cannot connect to X server". I also try to run with "xvfb-run python GUI.py", although it started to run but the graphical user interface didn't showed up, is there any suggestion?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In order to run a GUI application remotely on a Linux/Unix box, you need to have a X server running on your local machine and ready to accept a connection.  Easiest way to do this is to SSH in and enable `X11Forwarding` either in your client config, your personal version of the client config, or on the command line (ie, the `-X` or `-Y` options).

Us Linux folks already have an X server, as do them BSD folks.  Mac users can install it and it integrates quite nicely on OS X.  Windows users need to either pay some $ and buy a license for a commercial product, or use `cygwin-x`.